# Excel Conditional format chart

Tags: excel, charts, format, conditional-formatting

So i want to conditionally format this column chart. I want the column part where the values are between 0-30 to be red, from 31-70 to be yellow and from 71 to 100 to be green. Is this even possible in excel?
[Based on values in above cells (BEST...) conditionally format the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFVzF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Could do a stacked bar chart like so:
[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOn0.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).